How to create a client to launch mod SourceSDK
How to create your own client to run a mod without the official hl2.exe. I want to create a mod and a client for this mod. Where to start and if there is, I would like examples of a fully finished client and SDK
I am using Visual Studio 2022
I tried to look for examples of a client with a ready mod but I didn't find any

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
